# How do I get a label and radio buttons inline with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this should be simple, but the solution eludes me. My [test-site](http://writers-tryst-test.ron-tornambe.com/#/accounts) illustrates my frustration.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="choose-type" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label label-inline">Account Type</label>
    <div id="choose-type" class="col-sm-10 div-inline">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="user-type" id="writer" value="1" required > Writer
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="user-type" id="enabler" value="2" required> Enabler
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question because **class="radio-inline"** permit already to appear on the same line.

Comment: But you can change **class="col-sm-10 div-inline"** by **class="col-sm-8 div-inline"**. Besides you have problem on several fields on mobile version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this. You have padding in the divs which is throwing your bootstrap layout off (col-sm-10 and col-sm-2 don't have enough space). I have changed col-sm-10 to col-sm-8 to accommodate.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="choose-type" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label label-inline">Account Type</label>
    <div id="choose-type" class="col-sm-8 div-inline">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="user-type" id="writer" value="1" required=""> Writer
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="user-type" id="enabler" value="2" required=""> Enabler
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Woops, looks like I misinterpreted OP's Question, +1;
I recommend removing the redundant `radio-inline`'s nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're talking about the height difference between the text and the radio-button.
 Remove the second `radio-inline` from the `<input>` elements, the `radio-inline` from the `<label>` is sufficient.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="choose-type" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label label-inline">Account Type</label>
    <div id="choose-type" class="col-sm-10 div-inline">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="" name="user-type" id="writer" value="1" required > Writer
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="" name="user-type" id="enabler" value="2" required> Enabler
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```